# Control escape string

Tags: javascript

I have a function to get result for each group. The problem is I got an error because of escape string. How to control it.
Sampel e: O'neil

Here is my script:

```
function specificName(e) {

  var resultA;
  var resultB;
  var resultC;

  console.log("NAME:"+ e);

  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i].Nama_A == e) {
     resultA=A[i];
   }
 }

 for (var i = B.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(B[i].Nama_B == e){
    resultB=B[i];
  }
} 

for (var i = C.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(C[i].Nama_C ==e){
    resultC=C[i];
  }
}
```

I have try this.

```
var myStr2 = e.replace(/'/g, "''");
```

But it same.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Btw, `console.log` works much better if you pass it multiple arguments instead of using string concatenation. Change your line to `console.log("NAME:", e)`.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the quote, like:

```
var myStr2 = str.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
console.log(myStr2); // gives O\'neil
```